# Magento 2: Change compare icon in product detailed page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to change compare icon in product detailed page
for more info please find the attached image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below path :

```
/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/source/styles-m.css // that is default theme css path. if you are using theme than check with theme path.
```

to find below class

```
.product-social-links .action.tocompare:before {
    content: '\e61e'; // to replace with your icon.
}
```